# How to get average of three vector3 in Csharp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, average, oculus

I am trying to get the average of three vector3 by using the code below but I get an error when compiling saying

*"Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'method group'"*

This error is refering to the very last line in this example and I don't know how to fix it. What is that "method group"?

To let you get some background, the intended use of this code is to reposition the camera within an Oculus experience I am working on.

I don't really have such a big background into coding but starting to get into it. I managed to get to this point by trying to understand and merging several solutions given by the community. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this step.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class Calibration : MonoBehaviour
{
  Vector3 averagePos = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            
  Vector3[] positionArray = new[] { 
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), 
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
  };
}

 void Update()
 {

 Vector3 averagePos (Vector3[] positionArray)
                    {
                     float x = 0f;
                     float y = 0f;
                     float z = 0f;

                     foreach (Vector3 pos in positionArray)
                     {
                      x += pos.x;
                      y += pos.y;
                      z += pos.z;
                      }
                      return new Vector3 (x / positionArray.Length, y / positionArray.Length, z / positionArray.Length);                                            
                      }
                        
                     this.transform.position += averagePos;
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried static method `Vector3.Add()`? _(I don't know the unity3d yet)_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen There is no such method, static or instance. Unity vectors are added using the plus operator (thank god).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Vector3 averagePos (Vector3[] positionArray) {...}
    
    this.transform.position += averagePos;
```

Here `averagePos` is the name of a local function. You probably intended to call the function, so should have `this.transform.position += averagePos(something)` instead; or you could mean to set `this.averagePos = averagePos(something)` to save the result of calling the function. Either way, you need to give the compiler a bit more information so it can tell the difference between the local `averagePos` and the class-level field `averagePos` - either by using `this.` or renaming the local function to something else.

The compiler calls a reference to a method by its name a 'method group'. It does this because there could be more than one method in scope with that name, and because the context doesn't imply it is used as a bound method delegate or `Func<Vector3[], Vector3>`, so until it has enough information to decide what was meant, it holds the possible things that syntax could mean as a 'method group'.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that causes your code not to compile is that you are attempting to add a method to a vector. I am assuming you are confused because you don't realize `averagePos` is not a `Vector3` value. It is actually something called a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions), which is essentially a method within a method.

Or perhaps you do realize you've made a local function, in which case, you just have to add the argument to the function:

```
transform.position += averagePos(positionArray);
```

Anyway.. there are some other problems in the code, such as pointlessly splitting the vector into its dimensions to calculate the average, or making the average calculating method inaccessible to code outside `Update`. I would refactor it like this:

```
// maybe put this into another file
public static class Utilities
{
    public static Vector3 Average(Vector3[] vectors)
    {
        Vector3 sum = Vector3.zero;

        for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += vectors[i];
        }

        return sum / vectors.Length;
    }
}

public class Calibration : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3[] positionArray = new[] 
    {
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f),
    };

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position += Utilities.Average(positionArray);
    }
}
```